# Android Gradle Build Failure - failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cocos2d-x

I've created an Android Studio using the Cocos2d-X 3 python command line tool, but I am having some trouble with the generated project.

Whenever I open it or try to build it I get the following error:

```
21:05:01 Gradle sync failed: Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in: C:\Desenvolvimento\_Dev_Tools\Android\android-sdk
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

I've done some research on the internet and I found several questions regarding this and the answer to most of them was to the change the app\gradle.build script to this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ArmoniaGames.IgualOuDiferente"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Here is my Android SDK config:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

What I am doing wrong? Is there some configuration that I am missing, maybe with Cocos2d-X?

**EDIT**

Result of running the `android list targets` command:

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-23"
     Name: Android 6.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 23
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWea
rRound, AndroidWearRound360x360, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRound480x480, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidW
earRoundChin360x325, AndroidWearRoundChin360x330, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare320x320, AndroidWearRound, Android
WearRound360x360, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRound480x480, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidWearRoundChin360
x325, AndroidWearRoundChin360x330, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare320x320
 Tag/ABIs : android-tv/armeabi-v7a, android-tv/x86, android-wear/armeabi-v7a, android-wear/x86, default/armeabi-v7a, def
ault/x86, default/x86_64
----------
id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 6.0 (API level 23)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWea
rRound, AndroidWearRound360x360, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRound480x480, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidW
earRoundChin360x325, AndroidWearRoundChin360x330, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare320x320, AndroidWearRound, Android
WearRound360x360, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRound480x480, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidWearRoundChin360
x325, AndroidWearRoundChin360x330, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare320x320
 Tag/ABIs : google_apis/armeabi-v7a, google_apis/x86, google_apis/x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the "android-22" (SDK for Lollipop 5.1) because you didn't install it. On your screenshot I see that only the API level 23 is installed.

If you want to build to target the API 22, you will have to install it and modify your gradle to match the

"android-22" is the string equivalent 22. For example `compileSdkVersion 22`  and `compileSdkVersion "android-22"`  is equivalent. (same for the target sdk)

Note that you can have your compileSdkVersion to 23 and your targetSdkVersion to 22.

Comment: Hi, I understand. However I would like to build it for the API 23, which is the one that I currently have. Shouldn't it work given the configurations that I made above?

Comment: Your gradle file is good. If you go to the cocos2d properties, can you check that you are targeting `target=android-23` (not google api or another api level by using `android list targets`)

Comment: Hi, I've ran the `android list targets` command and pasted it on my question above. However I haven't found the cocos2d properties. Is it a config file? Could you tell me where it is?